# Why toggle checkbox returns false?

Tags: angular

I show checkboxes on the page.

When I click over it it is changed to `true/false`. If true the cehckbox should be checked.

Problem is when I click first checkbox it works, when click the second I get wrong `completed: false` in object `{id: 2, content: "CSS", completed: false}`, despite checkbox is checked:

[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu8fM.png)

Code is by link to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-data-binding-with-observable-dwfuk3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using ngModel directive wrong its [(ngModel)] not ([ngModel])

Comment: It has no sense, I removed `([ngModel])` the same issue.

Comment: Removing ngModel is also issue. You have to use correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes has rather a state (checked or not), not a value.
If you are changing the model value after click, use checkbox only for showing the curent state.
So i would change:

`[(ngModel)]="todo.completed"`

to `[checked]="todo.completed"`